# Sublime Text 2 - build can't find something on my path?

Tags: path, sublimetext2, build-system

I have the following coffeescript build file:

```
{
    "cmd": ["coffee", "-c", "$file"]
,   "selector": "source.coffee"
}
```

which when I try to run it gives me:

> [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified [cmd:  [u'coffee',u'-c', u'W:\mayapp\myscript.coffee']]
>
> [dir:  W:\myapp]
>
> [path: /usr/local/bin:C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Mercurial\;C:\Program
>   Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\strawberry\c\bin;C:\strawberry\perl\site\bin;C:\strawberry\perl\bin;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Bitvise SSH
>   Client;C:\Chocolatey\bin;C:\Users\George\AppData\Roaming\npm\;C:\Program
>   Files\Gallio\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;] [Finished]

In powershell

```
coffee -c w:\myapp\myscript.coffee
```

runs just fine leading me to think it's the `coffee` file from npm that the build system cannot find. Yet notice the npm directory IS on my path and `coffee.cmd` is absolutely in that directory

```
W:> get-command coffee | select path

Path
----
C:\Users\George\AppData\Roaming\npm\coffee.cmd
```

my best guess is that the error is due to that linux path prefixed to sublime's path variable but I have no idea where that is coming from it is not in my path variable outside of sublime.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to use the command name with extension - sublime was unable to infer it.

So:

```
{
    "cmd": ["coffee.cmd", "-c", "$file"]
,   "selector": "source.coffee"
}
```